# C++ grpc client to Nginx ssl

Tags: c++, nginx, ssl, http2, grpc-c++

I have a grpc server wrapped with nginx.
And I'm trying to write clients to it in different languages.
The python version works well

```
    cred = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials()
    channel = grpc.secure_channel(NAME, cred)
    stub = MyServiceStub(channel)
```

But analogical c++ code doesn't.

```
auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel(NAME, grpc::SslCredentials(grpc::SslCredentialsOptions()));
auto stub = MyService::NewStub(channel);
```

nginx version 1.16.1 (built with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017)

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name NAME;

    location / {
        return 302 grpc://NAME$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen  443 ssl http2;
    server_name NAME;
    ssl_certificate chain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key privkey.pem;

    location / {
        grpc_pass grpc://IP;
        grpc_read_timeout 3600;
    }


}
```

nginx access log print `"PRI * HTTP/2.0" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"` and in debug for bad request

```
[debug] 24255#0: *103047 http check ssl handshake
[debug] 24255#0: *103047 http recv(): 1
[debug] 24255#0: *103047 plain http
[debug] 24255#0: *103047 http wait request handler
```

but a good request get

```
[debug] 30192#0: *105029 http check ssl handshake
[debug] 30192#0: *105029 http recv(): 1
[debug] 30192#0: *105029 https ssl handshake: 0x16
[debug] 30192#0: *105029 tcp_nodelay
[debug] 30192#0: *105029 ssl get session: 5F263490:3
```

grpc version 1.34.0 and c++ client outputs errors

```
Failed parsing HTTP/2
Expected SETTINGS frame as the first frame, got frame type 80
failed to connect to all addresses
Trying to connect an http1.x server
```

I find a similar Go problem [How to find out why Nginx return 400 while use it as http/2 load balancer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54395350/how-to-find-out-why-nginx-return-400-while-use-it-as-http-2-load-balancer#comment95674566_54398632) , but don't know how to pass "h2" in c++.